# Unable to reindex titan 1.0.0 mixed index after adding existed property to it

Tags: elasticsearch, titan, gremlin

I am using **Titan 1.0.0** with cassandra backend and elasticsearch as index. I have user vertices with configured properties (*userId, email, fullName... etc*). Some of those properties are configured as mixed index in elasticsearch. Now I want to add an existed property (e.g. a **previously configured** property that was not included in the mixed index before) to the mixed index using:

```
 TitanManagement tm = graph.openManagement();
 tm.addIndexKey(tm.getGraphIndex("users"), tm.getPropertyKey("age"));
 tm.commit();
```

From now additional "*age*" property mapping is added to the elasticsearch. Each update of the "*age*" property of a user vertex add an "*age*" field to the elasticserch document. However in order to use this index properly in titan queries I must reindex my mixed graph index. At this point my problem starts. Referred to titan documentation, I need to do the following steps (using Gremlin):

```
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem

// Rollback or commit transactions on the graph which predate the index definition
graph.tx().rollback()

// Block until the SchemaStatus transitions from INSTALLED to REGISTERED
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "users")
    .status(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED)
    .timeout(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES) // set timeout to 10
    .call()
```

After 10 minute timeout the answer that was received:

```
==>GraphIndexStatusReport[success=false, indexName='users', targetStatus=REGISTERED,
   notConverged={age=INSTALLED, fullName=ENABLED, userId=ENABLED,
   userRegisterDate=ENABLED, userGender=ENABLED, email=ENABLED},
   converged={}, elapsed=PT10M0.173S]
```

And now, if I try to reindex as follows:

```
tm = graph.openManagement()
tm.updateIndex(tm.getGraphIndex("users"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
tm.commit()
```

I receive the error:

```
WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.olap.job.IndexRepairJob  - Index users has key age in an invalid status INSTALLED
ERROR com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.keycolumnvalue.scan.StandardScannerExecutor  - Exception trying to setup the job:
com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: The index users is in an invalid state and cannot be indexed. The following index keys have invalid status: age has status INSTALLED (status must be one of [REGISTERED, ENABLED])
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try chaining the call to `.get()` after `tm.updateIndex(tm.getGraphIndex("users"), SchemaAction.REINDEX)`? You missed that part from the example provided in the documentation.

Comment: @jbmusso yes, I tried with `.get()` method call. Just copy/paste mistake, edited my questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a new property to an existing index. Check [docs](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/indexes.html).

Comment: According to the Titan v1.0.0 documentation, [this can be done for Mixed Index](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#index-mixed).

Comment: Where? Could you please cite the section that says you can add a new property to an existing mixed index?

Comment: @M-T-A please check in section [8.1.2.1](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#_adding_property_keys) of Titan 1.0.0 documentation: "_If the property key has already been in use, adding the key requires the execution of a **reindex procedure** to ensure that the index contains all previously added elements._"

Comment: @OctopusES, that means you can add an existing property to a new index. But that doesn't mean you can add any property to an existing index.